# How to make automatic LP providing after time lock

Tags: ethereum, solidity, contract

I am learning solidity and want to create a contract that will lock token for Uniswap LP. What I've created is:

- List item
- on token creation I am creating uniswap pair with that token
- I am creating a Timelock for token amount assigned to creator address
- now on release() method I would like to automatically add liquidity with eth value that has been sent and token that was locked

Problem here is that to add LP to uniswap token needs to be approved and from what I see the only way to approve token is to first send this token to creator address.

Is it possible to make it automatic so that we don't need to trust contract creator to add LP after it has been released to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have non-standard ERC-20 token that allows perform approve for Uniswap contract addresses on special conditions (e.g. before a certain time or similar).

You would directly update `allowances` table in your token. You do not need to use `approve()` from ERC-20 because it is your token.

Comment: Thanks for answer, basically I've found that approve is not a problem because contract creator can do it by himself before doing release() on time lock contract.
What I would like to do is to automatically send token and eth to LP pair when calling release(). Do you think it is possible?

Comment: I do not see why it is not possible. You can program any kind of smart contracts you want, only imagination is your limit.